# Pandas Dataframe - Select from Unique Products

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the cars data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'car' : ['brand1_2020', 'brand2', 'brand3', 'brand1_2018', 'brand4'],
                 'score' : [5.2, 4.9, 5.0, 5.1, 4.1]})
```

I have to select top 3 cars with unique brands (for example, there are two columns for brand1: brand1_2020 and brand1_2018.. I need to select only one from brand1 with the highest score).

```
cars_filtered = df.iloc[np.argsort(np.abs(df['score']))[-3:]].car.tolist()
```

This produces: ['brand3', 'brand1_2018', 'brand1_2020'] but we need to get  ['brand2', 'brand3','brand1_2020'] .

How do we do that? :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider splitting the strings in the `'cars'` column and creating a new column called brand:

```
df['brand'] = [x[0] for x in df['car'].str.split("_")]
```

This will allow you to treat `'brand1_2021'` and `'brand1_2018'` as the same `'brand1'` category.

```
>>> df
           car  score   brand
0  brand1_2020    5.2  brand1
1       brand2    4.9  brand2
2       brand3    5.0  brand3
3  brand1_2018    5.1  brand1
4       brand4    4.1  brand4
```

Then you can sort the DataFrame by score in order from largest to smallest, drop any repeated entries under the `'brand'` column, and select the top three values in the original `'car'` column:

```
df.sort_values(by="score", ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset="brand").car[0:3].to_list()
```

Output:

```
['brand1_2020', 'brand3', 'brand2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by on the prefixes (`brand1`, ...), get the booleans, and finally keep the top three:

```py
bools = df.car.str.split('_').str[0]
bools = df.groupby(bools).score.transform('max')
df.loc[df.score == bools].nlargest(3, 'score').car.tolist()

['brand1_2020', 'brand3', 'brand2']
```

Answer (score 0):

df['brand'] = [x[0] for x in df['car'].str.split("_")]
df.sort_values(by="score", ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset="brand").car[0:3].to_list()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).